# get data from in gridview

Tags: datagridview

how Can I get data that fill gridview?

I want to get value One of feild that I see in grid view.

Comment: What technology are you refering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a postback, you will not have access to the original data that filled the gridview. However, ViewState will maintain all of the values of the controls that the GridView created. The only way you will be able to accomplish this on a postback is through storing the value in some control or column and accessing that columns value.